# Android Custom ListView/Adapter

Tags: android, list, android-listview, adapter

I am wanting to change my listView from the normal ArrayAdapter (simple_list_item_1) to something more like this:

Name.....     Score(center right).
Date (under name)

So There's 3 Views...

1. name
2. date
3. score

I've looked up how to make custom adapters and layouts but they are all very confusing. I just want a simple fix that I can add to an existing project.

Here's my code for my list right now:

```
//update listView
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(GradesActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
mListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: all the data is fine but I just don't know how to design/ implement a custom listview

Comment: You need to use `CustomAdapter` for it.

Comment: `CustomAdapter` and `custom_layout` for row not `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had the SAME problem last week. My solution was a tutorial on the internet: **http://androidtuts4u.blogspot.com.br/2013/02/android-list-view-using-custom-adapter.html**

Just copying and pasting the code onto a temporary project (it will take less than 15 minutes) will help you understand how simple it is and also make it very clear so you can implement it into your original project. I hope it helps!

Peace!

Comment: I am truly gladly it worked. I hope you have fun and success with your project. Peace :)

Answer (score 0):

ArrayAdapter can't auto binding three view

You can try SimpleAdapter or extend BaseAdapter implements it youself

This is Google's training

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/lists.html

And here is a sample of SimpleAdapter http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/UsingSimpleAdaptertofilldatatoListView.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are many fixes you need to do
1. Create a class that extends BaseAdapter.

2. Override all the methods create a constructor of that class that will initialize listitems
3. You are just passing names
   `listView listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(GradesActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);`

Instead of just names create a class that contains three elements you need I.e name date and score and make there get and set methods
And the object of the class will be saved in a list.
4. In getview method you have to set these variables